# How to open large images in Visual studio 2012 express?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2012, drawing

I want to open a 86009x6781 png image in c# using the system drawing class, but I get a `c# System.OverflowException` exception. This is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ImageSplit
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap src = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/me/Desktop/Pic/Class_UML.png") as Bitmap;

        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried an `Image` object?

Comment: How do I use it, can you show code?

Comment: Image i;
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open("path", FileMode.Open)) { 
                i = Image.FromStream(fs);
            }

Comment: it still got the same error.